# Titan 1.0.0 FIXED configuration "set-vertex-id" - can be overriden?

Tags: configuration, titan, vertex

I'm trying to override the graph.set-vertex-id configuration in Titan 1.0.0

By loading the configuration from an xml file:

```
    cache.db-cache-time = 180000
    cache.db-cache-size = 0.25
    graph.set-vertex-id=true
    storage.batch-loading=true
....
```

I'm getting the error :

```
 Local setting graph.set-vertex-id=true (Type: FIXED) is overridden by globally managed value (false).  Use the ManagementSystem interface instead of the local configuration to control this setting.
```

I also tried

```
   BaseConfiguration configuration = new BaseConfiguration();
    configuration.setProperty("storage.hostname", "any_hostname");
    configuration.setProperty("storage.backend", "thrift");
    configuration.setProperty("graph.set-vertex-id", Boolean.TRUE);

titanGraph = TitanFactory.open(configuration);
```

But by checking the config with TitanManagement

```
   titanGraph.openManagement().get("graph.set-vertex-id");
```

I can see that it's still 'false'.

Has anyone tried to assign custom vertices ids in this version of Titan? Before the upgrade we used Titan 0.4.2 and it worked just fine.

The documentation (http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/configuration.html ) says that

```
GLOBAL: These options are always read from the cluster configuration and cannot be overwritten on an instance basis.
FIXED: Like GLOBAL, but the value cannot be changed once the Titan cluster is initialized.
When the first Titan instance in a cluster is started, the global configuration options are initialized from the provided local configuration file. Subsequently changing global configuration options is done through Titan’s management API.     
To access the management API, call g.getManagementSystem() on an open Titan instance handle g. For example, to change the default caching behavior on a Titan cluster:

    mgmt = graph.openManagement()
    mgmt.get('cache.db-cache')
    // Prints the current config setting
    mgmt.set('cache.db-cache', true)
    // Changes option
    mgmt.get('cache.db-cache')
    // Prints 'true'
    mgmt.commit()
    // Changes take effect
```

Firstly, there is no getManagementSystem() on a graph in Titan 1.0.0. Secondly, overriding the "graph.set-vertex-id" config like that will throw another error, because at this point the graph is already initialised:

```
 Cannot change the fixed configuration option: root.graph.set-vertex-id
```

Thank you !